# Id attributes are missing in OneNote page content fetched via Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

We are creating a OneNote page using the below Graph endpoint. Several id attributes are present in the HTML content of this page.

```
POST .. groups/{group-id}/onenote/sections/{section-id}/pages
```

To get the OneNote page content again, we are using the below graph end point.

```
GET ..groups/{group-id}/onenote/pages/{page-id}/content?includeIds=true
```

In the case of one of our customers, when we get the page content, we don't see those id attributes that we added when creating the page. Other customers do not experience this problem.

We checked that we did not PATCH anything on that page before it started returning page content without id attributes.

In debugging, we noticed that if we create a OneNote page and get the page content immediately, we get the IDs back, but if we do it later, we don't.

Here are the details of the latest get request for that page content.

```
curl $'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/e07ccbcc-3464-4777-aa3a-466cc0db328c/onenote/pages/1-1ea50c06f867479a84ffa6a1f3710e0d\u002157-7b03c43d-87ff-4692-8664-d3a42822b7ed/content?includeIds=true' \
   -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
   -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
   -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="92"' \
   -H 'Pragma: no-cache' \
   -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
   -H 'Authorization: Bearer 
   -H 'client-request-id: 95a44839-0407-4fe7-b497-294c9375ea1f' \
   -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
   -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36 Edg/92.0.902.84' \
   -H 'If-Modified-Since: Mon: 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT' \
   -H 'Origin: https://app.boarddecisions.com' \
   -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site' \
   -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
   -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
   -H 'Referer: https://app.boarddecisions.com/' \
   -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8' \
   --compressed
```

**Additional Details about ids -**

In OneNote page content, for different table elements, we have id attributes.
Example -

```
 <table border="1" data-type="tasks" id="meetingDecisionsTable" style="width:1080px">
 ......
 </table>
```

We usually get these IDs back in the data-id attribute like below.
[image]

For one specific customer, we are not getting any data-id attribute in the page content. We are unable to reproduce this issue outside of the customer's environment. Therefore, it should be tracked with the request id provided above.